# Can I use of "of" instead of "for" in "interventions of cultural heritage"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Does the following sound "ok" in terms of meaning and use of English?

"Decision-Making in Conservation & Restoration Interventions of Cultural Heritage"

Particularly, I am concerned about the use of the word "of" in the end (note that "Cultural Heritage" may refer either to the actual object of conservation (e.g. a monument) or the domain):

(the reason I am asking is that this is actually a published paper title which unfortunately cannot be changed anymore...)

Comment: ***of*** (or ***by***) would tend to imply there's an organization called "Cultural Heritage" that's responsible for making the specific "conservation interventions" referred to by your noun phrase. But ***for*** implies that (enhancing or preserving) "cultural heritage" is the ***reason*** these interventions are being made. But since you capitalized "Cultural Heritage", I assume you think of that as the name of an organization, in which case ***by*** is more common than ***of***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "of" is possible in the sense "done to", as in  the sentence "the oppression of a nation","the destruction of the forest" etc.(I think)

Comment: @Sam: I think it's stretching a point to say ***of*** can mean ***done to***. Approximately, in such contexts, it just means ***relating to***, which can imply a wide range of relationships. We'd be here until doomsday if we wanted to list all possible ways of expressing those relationships!

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, consider the "cultural heritage" not capitalized (I also corrected in the question).

Comment: @Sam Yes that was what I had in mind, i.e. whether "of" can imply "done to" in this context (as is the case with "for" I suppose). Indeed, the case sounds analogous to "oppression of a nation" etc. So, if "for" and "of" can be used to imply "done to", can they can be used interchangeably in such cases?

Comment: "conservation interventions" is meaningless in English.

Comment: You need to come up with another term that is not intervention: action or actions or measures or steps, for example.

Comment: @Lambie: Or just throw the word ***interventions*** out completely, as AndyBonner points out. *Conservation of  heritage* makes sense, but *action / measures steps of heritage* doesn't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Action for the conservation of cultural heritage

Comment: This question was closed because it violates our rule against requests for proofreading. Reworded, it is still a request for proofreading. If you are trying to learn the difference in usage or meaning between "of" and "for", perhaps in the context of "intervention", that would be appropriate for this site. You could even use that headline as an example. But if you just want to know if that headline is grammatically correct, sorry, we don't provide that service on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's causing confusions is that the following would work:

> Conservation of cultural heritage

It's been suggested in comments that "of" can be read as "done to." This works best, though, when the word before "of" is a verb (or a phrase that does the work of a verb).

But when you say "conservation interventions of," then "conservation interventions" becomes a phrase that acts like a noun, and the meaning of "of" shifts to "related to or belonging to."

Also, I'm not sure "conservation interventions" works terribly well as a phrase to begin with. We're definitely talking about interventions, and their goal is conservation, but I'm not sure that putting them together as a phrase makes sense. I might render the whole thing as something like

> Interventions for conservation of cultural heritage

or

> Interventions to conserve cultural heritage

... or similar.

Comment: Often, French, Spanish and Portuguese and probably Italian use intervention where we'd say actions or action or measures or some other term. And thus, it might well be: action for the conservation of cultural heritage.